# Get my SVG to stay inline with other elements

Tags: html, css, svg, position

I am trying to get my SVG image to stay inline with the other elements I have on the page to make it responsive. Right now, when I shrink the browser, the SVG shifts up and down. How can I get it to stay in one place? I will include pictures of what is happening as well as code.

```
<div id="svgContainer">
    <svg id="svg" viewBox="50 54 100 100">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="13.1" style="stroke: white; fill: white;"/>
        <text x="97" y="101" id="currentTemp" font-size="3" font-weight="bold" style="fill: #507282">{{currentTemp}}&#176;F</text>
        <circle class="background" cx="100" cy="100" r="6" stroke="#F5F2EA" />
        <circle class="background" cx="100" cy="100" r="9" stroke="#eddfbb" />
        <circle class="background" cx="100" cy="100" r="12" stroke="#DCE3E6" />
        <circle id="line1" class="overlayLine" cx="100" cy="100" r="6" stroke="#CDBD97" stroke-dasharray="0, 3000" stroke-dashoffset="126" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />
        <circle id="line2" class="overlayLine" cx="100" cy="100" r="9" stroke="#C9AC68" stroke-dasharray="0, 3000" stroke-dashoffset="188" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />
        <circle id="line3" class="overlayLine" cx="100" cy="100" r="12" stroke="#507282" stroke-dasharray="0, 3000" stroke-dashoffset="251" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@keyframes dash {
    to {
      stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
.background {
    stroke-width: 2.7;
    fill: none;
}
.overlayLine {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 2.7;
    animation: dash 2s linear forwards;
}
#svg{
    position: absolute;
    top: -425px;
    left: 335px;
}
#svgContainer{
    width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
 function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
     min = Math.ceil(min);
     max = Math.floor(max);
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; //The maximum is inclusive and the minimum is inclusive 
 }

 function setStop(id, radius, stop){
     var c = document.getElementById(id);
     c.className = "background";
     var stopVal = Math.PI * radius * 2 * (stop/10);
     c.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", stopVal + ", 3000");
     c.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", stopVal);
     c.className = "overlayLine";
 }

 function randomStops(){
     setStop("line1", 6, getRandomIntInclusive(1, 10));
     setStop("line2", 9, getRandomIntInclusive(1, 10));
     setStop("line3", 12, getRandomIntInclusive(1, 10));
 }
 randomStops();
```

[looks good on full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVrZL.png)

[bad when shrinking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpNou.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can see the problem in action. The small snippet of the page that you have provided isn't enough to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got it temporarily working with percentages on the 'left' and 'top' css attributes. If there is a better way to do it, I would love to hear.